# How to get a specific value from firebase realtime database using kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get the sum of every expense's amount

Here's the importIncome Function:

```
private fun importIncome() {
    val myPref = getSharedPreferences("MY_PRE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val savedUsername = myPref.getString("USERNAME", "Admin").toString()
    //getting values from user and saving them into variables
    val title = etIncTitle.text.toString()
    val description = etIncDescription.text.toString()
    val amount = etIncAmount.text.toString()
    val isIncome: String = "true"

    if (title.isEmpty() or amount.isEmpty() or description.isEmpty()) {
        Snackbar.make(btnImportIncome, "Please Fill all Fields!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    } else {
        val expenseID = dbRef.push().key!!
        val expense = ExpenseModel(savedUsername, title, description, amount, isIncome)

        dbRef.child(expenseID).setValue(expense)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                Snackbar.make(btnImportIncome, "Income Added!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                etIncTitle.setText("")
                etIncDescription.setText("")
                etIncAmount.setText("")
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                Snackbar.make(btnImportIncome, "Something went wrong!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            }
    }
}
```

[image: Realtime Database]

I really can't figure out a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the sum of all `amount` values, you have to create a reference that points to the `Tcd...a72` node. Assuming that this node is represented by the `uid` of the user and this node exists in a `users` node, then please use the following lines of code:

```
val auth = Firebase.auth
val uid = auth.currentUser?.uid
val db = Firebase.database.reference
val usersRef = db.child("users")
usersRef.child(uid).get().addOnCompleteListener {
    if (it.isSuccessful) {
        val snapshot = it.result
        val amounts = mutableListOf<Int>()
        for (userSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
            val amount = userSnapshot.child("amount").getValue(String::class.java)
            amount?.let {
                amounts.add(amount.toInt())   
            }
        }
        //Do what you need to do with the list
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "${it.exception?.message}") //Never ignore potential errors!
    }
}
```

While this code will work, as it converts the `String` value into `Int`, it's better to store the value of `amount` as a number and **not** as a `String`.